# How to differentiate between directories created manually and directories created by installed programs?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, python, metadata, dir

On my Ubuntu laptop, I want to differentiate between directories I created manually and directories created by programs that I install for coding purposes (in Python).

I have searched a lot, but it seems that it's somewhat impossible.

The normal and boring approach would be to know the name of the program you installed, and it's good from there.

It seems like there's not enough metadata to provide such information.

Comment: Correct. If you know the *time* the folder was created, and the *time* that the applications created folders, it might give you a clue -- but that is not conclusive proof. In the future, give folders distinct names, both your own and those created by the app.

Comment: A folder created "by you" is by definition also created by "a program". The filesystem only tracks the user who runs programs that creates folders, not the program itself. As far as the OS and filesystem is concerned there is no difference between python creating a folder, you running the shell command to create a folder or you creating a folder using the file explorer, they all run the same OS function to create a folder and that tracks only users, not programs.

Comment: Define "manually" vs "by programs". Note `mkdir`, `mc`, `dolphin` or `nautilus` are programs. Only you can tell if your `mc` is "installed for coding purposes" or not. Even `mkdir` vs everything else is problematic because while programs can and should use `mkdir(2)` (system call) directly, they *may* use `mkdir(1)` (program).

Comment: You can from now on mark every directory you create "manually" – by adding some extended attribute or by simply putting an empty `.manually` file or so. Automating this may or may not be easy, depending on your definition of "manually". And of course this won't work retroactively.